# teamcity - 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: teamcity

i'm using teamcity 5.1.5.. trying to build an MSBuild project with an AfterDeploy target which calls a java function..

i get the following error: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I've tested the java command on the build server and the agent servers and they all run the command..but it seems it fails when running through teamcity.

any ideas?

i've checked the build agent env vars and they seem correctly setup:

> Environment variables defined in the
>   agent configuration file
>
> JAVA_HOME   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
>
> JDK_16    C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
>
> TEAMCITY_JRE  C:\TeamCity\jre

the only thing i notice is that the java.exe are actually in the bin folders here not the root folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build Agent runs from the SYSTEM account by default. SYSTEM account environment variables differ from your normal account which you've used for testing. I suspect that java.exe is not in PATH for the SYSTEM account. Either adjust PATH by adding JDK_HOME\bin to it or configure the Agent service to run from a different account.

Remember you need to restart the build agent service before changes to PATH will take effect.

Comment: the path is added to the environment settings of the user account under windows.  i cant seem to find anywhere to manually edit those Build Agent settings anywhere.. they seem to be predefined somewhere else.

Comment: You can override the PATH via buildAgent.properties file by defining system.PATH property or specify custom environment for this build configuration via TeamCity UI, refer to the documentation for details. Echo PATH from your build script to verify the actual value used, check if java.exe can be invoked with this PATH value.

Comment: Remember you need to restart the build agent service before changes to PATH will take effect

Comment: @JacoPretorius you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run your build agent service under a local administrator account (this might be preferred for several reasons), but there is a bug in TeamCity where only the USER environment variables (for example the PATH) are used by the agent, not SYSTEM+USER as normal in Windows.

So if you have a path defined for the user, the system paths are unknown by the agent!

The workaround right now (verified) is to add the user path to the system path and delete the user path (under System/Avanced System Settings/Environment Variables).

Bug here and a (not solved as of 2012-01-29):
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/276957

Comment: This fixed it for me. To be clear, fixed this ensuring I had user environmental variable set "JAVA_HOME" to "C:\TeamCity\jre". Which is the default install path for jre when installing Team City. The key bit being User Environmental Variable, not System.

Answer (score 0):

We run the agent under a normal user account. Java can be found in an interactive session, but not in the TeamCity builds. I had to add the java bin directory to the PATH variable of the user. After a log off/log in, the java command could then be found by the TeamCity builds.